# How do I run a CronJob inside a container with a predefined Image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes Deployment, in whose Pods I need a command run periodically.
The Kubernetes `CronJob` object creates a new Pod.
I would prefer to specify a cronjob, that runs inside the container of the Pod.
Is there any way, I can specify this in the deployment yaml?

I have no access to the Dockerfile, but am using pre-built Images.

Comment: Why is "inside the pod" important?  Usually a pod runs one container, and a container runs one process; maybe you could add an HTTP endpoint to the process to trigger whatever activity needs to be run?

Comment: Did the offered solution help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what I was trying to do is actually not really meant to be done.
I was not able to find a reasonable way to achieve this with purely pre-built images. All solutions ended up requiring some form of custom image as a sidecar or modifying the original Dockerfile.

How I solved my problem:

My CronJob was supposed to check a file mounted into the container file system as a ConfigMap, I opted for a sidecar, that has the ConfigMap mounted as well.
Instead of a conventional CronJob I opted for a shell script, that periodically did what I needed it to do and had this shell script run as the entry point of my alpine sidecar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as into `deploy.yaml`, where this job will run on 25th of every month and copy `app.xml` file to the `/mount` directory of the `PersistentVolume` on `Kubernetes Cluster` as below:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: app-feed-fio
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  storageClassName: fileshare
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-fio-scripts
data:
  appupdater.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
    set -x

    curl https://example.com/xyz.xml -o /mount/app.xml -v

    ls -la /mount

    cat /mount/app.xml

---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: app-feed-job
spec:
  schedule: "00 00 25 * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1500
            fsGroup: 1500
    #        supplementalGroups: [0]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
          - name: appupdater
            image: {container registry path}/app-feed-fio:v0.0.0
            command: ["/scripts/appupdater.sh"]
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: 100Mi
                cpu: 0.1
              limits:
                memory: 100Mi
                cpu: 0.1
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /mount
              name: fileshare        
            - mountPath: /scripts
              name: scripts    
          volumes:
          - name: fileshare
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: app-fio-pvc
          - name: scripts
            configMap:
              name: app-fio-scripts
              defaultMode: 0777
```

And, in `Dockerfile` as below:-

```
from ubuntu:focal
run apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y fio curl && \
    apt-get autoremove --purge && \
    apt-get clean && \
    mkdir /mount && \
    groupadd -g 1500 fio && \
    useradd -u 1500 -g 1500 fio

user 1500:1500
volume /mount
```